# Should I use multiple Cloud Load Balancers for multiple Cloud Run APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have multiple ESPv2 APIs hosted on Cloud Run. One for each service, each with their own *.run.app URIs.

My question is should I setup multiple Google Cloud Load Balancers, one for each Cloud Run service or map multiple Cloud Run services to the same Cloud Load Balancer.

Comment: What are your requirement? Both solution are valid, depend on your constraint!

Comment: Details and context are important. First question, why do you need a load balancer? Start with this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask